# Given $x$, find $n$ such that $1 + 2 + 3 + ... n = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a number $x$, how do we find a value $n$ such that 
$$
1+2+3+...+n =x
$$
This is how far I've gotten:
$$
x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
$$
2x = n(n+1)
$$
What do I do from here???

Comment: Hint:  Quadratic formula

Comment: @lulu Oh.......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then we will have $n^2+n-2x=0$

You can find solution for $n$ if and only if $x$ is a natural number and $\Delta=1^2-4\times 1 \times (-2x)=8x+1\ge0$, which is true for all nautral numbers $x$.

Then we will have $n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$ or $n=\frac{-1-\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$, but we will only take the positive integer solution, eliminate any non-integer solution.

Note that $8x+1$ must be a perfect square number so that $n$ can be a positive integer.

Comment: Note that $8x+1$, if a square, is always going to be odd, so specifying that isn't necessary.

Comment: So $n=\max(\frac{-1+\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}, \frac{-1-\sqrt{8x+1}}{2})$?

Comment: Note that $8x+1$ will always be odd, so the only condition is that it is a square.

Comment: @user5011: Well, yes, but it's simpler just to say $n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8x+1}}2.$

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thanks a lot!$n = \frac{-1+\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve $$ n^2+n-2x =0$$

As you know this quadratic equation may or may not have integer solutions.

For example $ x=55$ results in $n=10$ but $x=50$ does not have a round solution.